# .NET core 3.1 C# nswag file upload

Tags: c#, .net-core, nswag

I'm trying to upload a file to a C# application that is based on a Openapi specification. NSwag is used to generate the most of the C# code and I override the functions of the base class that is generated.

The Openapi specification that I have at this point is the following (relevant part):

```yaml
/upload:
    post:
      operationId: uploadFile
      tags:
        - file
      requestBody:
        description: The file to be uploaded
        required: True
        content:
          application/octet-stream:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: binary
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Returns a test message for now
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
        default:
          description: Unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
```

with the ErrorResponse scheme at the components section of the file (not included in the code block).

The generated code is the following:

```cs
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NSwag", "13.4.2.0 (NJsonSchema v10.1.11.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0))")]
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api/test")]
    public abstract class FileControllerBase : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
    {
        /// <param name="body">The file to be uploaded</param>
        /// <returns>Returns a test message for now</returns>
        [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPost, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("upload")]
        public abstract System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> UploadFile(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile body, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    
    }
```

And the override function (in the inherited class):

```cs
public override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> UploadFile(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile body, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

            //body parameter is always zero...
            await Task.Delay(10); // To "mislead" the async in the function definition, is needed in the real application
            if (body != null) {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Null");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Null"); // is always the outcome of the request
            }
            return "result"; //return random string
        }
```

Other useful information:

- NSwag version: 13.4.2
- Openapi version: 3.0.3
- Using the swagger UI to test the endpoints and verifying with wireshark that the request is properly send over with the data.

Now the question is, am I doing something wrong here? I cannot seem to get this working and I have tried all kinds of approaches to define the endpoint (using multipart/form-data, ...). Also tried it with postman to see if the issue is within Swagger UI, but the result is the same.

Comment: if you set a break point on `await Task.Delay(10);`, does your controller get hit?

Comment: Yes it does get hit.

Comment: ok that is good ! does your `body` parameter contain any values? Or is it null? If it is null, the most likely issue is your POST. Are you sure that the file is being set to the right property, e.g. `body`. Perhaps you could try a local tool, such as Postman.

https://pasteboard.co/JnZDPaf.png

Comment: Cam you try with the latest versions? There were some improvements in this area...